# How to reverse an array recursively using RISC-V?

Tags: recursion, assembly, riscv

I really have absolutely no idea how to do this, seems like the only solution online is behind a paywall. This is all I have:

```
.data
array: .word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
.text
main:
la x12, array
addi x13, x0, 7
addi x13, x13, -1
slli x13, x13, 2
add x13, x13, x12
jal x1, reverse
beq x0, x0, END
##### the function would start here #####
reverse: jalr x0, 0(x1)
##### and end here #####
END: add x1, x0, x10
```

The procedure receives two memory locations, the start position and the end position of the array.
My guess was something like using `srli`, but I'm 99.9% sure it's wrong.

(this is not for a college assignment btw, just an unnecessarily long revision exercise that's been haunting me for a week and now my brain freezes every time I look at a single line of assembly code)

Comment: Do it in C first.  Then translate to assembly.  Btw, function calling is an advanced topic.

Comment: How would you do it iteratively?  e.g. the standard algorithm is to walk pointers in towards each other from the start/end.  (or start/length if you want).  You can turn a simple loop into recursion, making it much less efficient and more complicated to implement, as an exercise in showing why recursion sucks in asm for anything that doesn't naturally benefit from a stack (like binary tree traversal, or the Ackermann function.)